# Como configurar o SDL2 com CMake no Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Estou tentando configurar a biblioteca [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/) em um Projeto CMake do zero, criado com o Visual Studio. Estou seguindo vários tutoriais na internet, cada um mais diferente que o outro, e sinceramente estou muito confuso com tudo isso.

Tomei como base [esse tutorial](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake/) para configurar o meu projeto e, para iniciar, criei um "CMake Project" do zero utilizando o Visual Studio. Após iniciar, editei meu arquivo CMake assim:

```
# Versão mínima do CMake
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Nome do projeto
project ("SDLTest")

# Diretórios SDL2
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR "include/SDL2")
set(SDL2_LIBRARY_DIR "lib/SDL2/x86")

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

link_directories(${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIR})

# Adiciona o executável do projeto
add_executable (SDLTest "src/SDLTest.cpp" "src/SDLTest.h")

target_link_libraries(SDLTest -lSDL2 -lSDL2main)
```

E o meu arquivo main `SDLTest.cpp` está programado para exibir uma janela simples do SDL2:

```
#include "SDLTest.h"

#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "SDL2Test",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640,
        480,
        0
    );

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

O projeto está configurando o CMake através do Visual Studio e nenhum erro é apresentado, até a hora de fazer o Debug:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Olá bio. Você usa nuget?

Comment: Oi @GuilhermeNascimento, não uso não, estou iniciando em C++ e essa é minha primeira experiência tentando configurar um projeto com SDL2. E já empaquei nisso. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A versão atual de Visual Studio, 17.6.2 de 27 de maio, 2023, inclui suporte para o gerenciador de pacotes `vcpkg` com mais de 1500 pacotes. É um produto open source e atualizado constantemente. Basta habilitar no instalador, mesmo na versão `Community`.

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

A partir daí pode ativar qualquer biblioteca na extensa lista.

Pode usar o `vcpkg` direto no `Developer Prompt` uma vez que tenha habilitado no instalador. Apenas use o botão direito, selecione o projeto e clique `Abrir no Terminal`.

Acho que é a maneira recomendada hoje em dia de fazer isso. Claro que pode baixar a versão para a sua plataforma e ajustar os diretórios e compilar tudo.

Eis a lista do que tem hoje lá no `vcpkg` para `sdl2`:

```
sdl2                     2.0.14#4         Simple DirectMedia Layer is a cross-platform development library designed ...
sdl2[vulkan]                              Vulkan functionality for SDL
sdl2-gfx                 1.0.4#7          Graphics primitives (line, circle, rectangle etc.) with AA support, rotozo...
sdl2-image               2.0.5#1          SDL_image is an image file loading library. It loads images as SDL surface...
sdl2-image[libjpeg-turbo]                 Support for JPEG image format
sdl2-image[libwebp]                       Support for WEBP image format.
sdl2-image[tiff]                          Support for TIFF image format
sdl2-mixer               2.0.4#11         Multi-channel audio mixer library for SDL.
sdl2-mixer[dynamic-load]                  Load plugins with dynamic call.
sdl2-mixer[libflac]                       Support for FLAC audio format.
sdl2-mixer[libmodplug]                    Support for MOD audio format.
sdl2-mixer[libvorbis]                     Support for OGG Vorbis audio format.
sdl2-mixer[mpg123]                        Support for MP3 audio format.
sdl2-mixer[nativemidi]                    Support for MIDI audio format on Windows and macOS.
sdl2-mixer[opusfile]                      Support for Opus audio format.
sdl2-net                 2.0.1-8          Networking library for SDL
sdl2-ttf                 2.0.15-3         A library for rendering TrueType fonts with SDL
sdl2pp                   0.16.1           C++11 bindings/wrapper for SDL2
```

Para ver todos os pacotes apenas use `vcpkg search`. Vai ser que `Qt5`, `wxwidgets`, `Vulkan` e `Opengl` estão na lista também.

#### Exemplo

Usando **seu programa** e esses arquivos na pasta do projeto

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
set (CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

find_package(sdl2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable (SDLTest "SDLTest.cpp")
target_link_libraries(SDLTest PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2 SDL2::SDL2main)
```

E esse `vcpkg.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/main/docs/vcpkg.schema.json",
  "name": "sop23-0612-sdl",
  "version": "0.15.2",
  "dependencies": [
    "sdl2",
    {
      "name": "sdl2",
      "default-features": true
    }
  ]
}
```

trás a referência para a biblioteca.

O arquivo `cpp` do exemplo

```
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "SDL2Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
        window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(
        renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(3000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();    return 0;
}
```

E roda ok. IntelliSense está disponível

[image: Color Coding e IntelliSense]

No rápido teste que fiz deixei o projeto em uma pasta dentro de um projeto maior, e então tem mais alguns arquivos na pasta principal. Não sei se precisa de todos.

#### CMakeLists.txt do projeto

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.20)
project ("sop23-0612-sdl")
set (CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/usr/local/src/SDL2-2.26.5/cmake")
add_subdirectory ("sop23-0612-sdl")
```

#### CMakePresets.json

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "windows-base",
            "hidden": true,
            "generator": "Ninja",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
            "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "cl.exe",
                "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "cl.exe"
            },
            "condition": {
                "type": "equals",
                "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
                "rhs": "Windows"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "x64-debug",
            "displayName": "x64 Debug",
            "inherits": "windows-base",
            "architecture": {
                "value": "x64",
                "strategy": "external"
            },
          "cacheVariables": {
            "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
            "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": {
                "value": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
                "type": "FILEPATH"
            }
          }
        },
        {
            "name": "x64-release",
            "displayName": "x64 Release",
            "inherits": "x64-debug",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "x86-debug",
            "displayName": "x86 Debug",
            "inherits": "windows-base",
            "architecture": {
                "value": "x86",
                "strategy": "external"
            },
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "x86-release",
            "displayName": "x86 Release",
            "inherits": "x86-debug",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### vcpkg-configuration.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/main/docs/vcpkg-configuration.schema.json",
  "default-registry": {
    "kind": "git",
    "repository": "https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg",
    "baseline": "eefee7408133f3a0fef711ef9c6a3677b7e06fd7"
  },
  "overlay-triplets": [ "./triplets" ]
}
```

#### vcpkg.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/main/docs/vcpkg.schema.json",
  "name": "sop23-0612-sdl",
  "version": "0.15.2",
  "dependencies": [
    "sdl2",
    {
      "name": "sdl2",
      "default-features": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Deixei uma cópia de `SDL2.dll` na pasta de `build` do projeto. Dá pra apontar para ela usando as variáveis do `CMake`.

Isso serve para rodar qualquer pacote oferecido pelo `vcpkg` usando `CMake`